# Chrome Extension, send data between tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a simple extension, but I cannot figure out how to move on. I guess it's a 'simple' question.

The scenario:

- The user select an text
- Opens the contextual menu and hit the extension
- A new tab will open
- Fill a textarea w/ the selected/highlighted text

I did the first three items, and to the fourth I tried chrome.tabs.query/executeScript/messaging, ajax post… without success.

```
function sendReport() {
    return function(info, tab) {
        var selectedText = info.selectionText;
        var cr_url = 'http://localhost/cr/index.php';
        var tab = chrome.tabs.create({ url: cr_url }, function(tab){

        });
    }
}

var OgameToConverter = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Enviar Relatório",
    "contexts": ["selection"],
    "onclick": sendReport()
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can send messages between tabs by using [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) or [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage). To receiving the message, add an listener for the message on the receiving tab by using the [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) method.

Example:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: cr_url }, function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(){});
});
```

In the tab:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    // do what you want to the message
});
```

Or, you can create the window with [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open), send the message with [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) and recieve the message by catching the `Message` event with something like `window.addEventListener("message", ...);`

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps I'm building this in the wrong way…
I've the Page 1 - http://example.com, when I highlight a text and hit the extension item on contextual menu, it'll open the Page 2 - http://stuff.org (different website) and fill a textarea with that selected text

So when you say 'in the tab', what you mean?

Comment: I mean this code will run on the tab you want to past the text on.

Comment: @0xcaff just a bit update. Extra closing bracket after `{greeting: "hello"}` need to be removed. I was unable to edit your answer as StackOverflow expect at least  6 characters of change for edit!!!